# How to sendOrderedBroadcast to other APP with custom permission?

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

My requirement is, from one APP I want to notify another APP some events with broadcast, but I don't want the other APPs also receive the broadcast. So I think sendOrderedBroadcast with permission is a good solution.

Then my test looks like this:

**BCSender APP:** 
which will define a custom permission, and send broadcast with this permission:

```
<permission 
    android:protectionLevel="normal"
    android:name="com.czou.permission.BC" />
```

The only activity in BCSender:

```
package com.example.bcsender;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String BC_PERMISSION = "com.czou.permission.BC";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendBroadcast();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void sendBroadcast()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.czou_broadcast");
        intent.putExtra("msg", "hello from czou");
        sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, BC_PERMISSION);
        //sendBroadcast(intent, BC_PERMISSION);
    }    
}
```

**BCReceiverA APP:**
 Which will declare the permission defined in BCSender APP and register broadcast receiver:

```
<user-permission android:name="com.czou.permission.BC" />
```

The only activity in BCReceiverA:

```
package com.example.bcreceivera;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {        
    private static String TAG = "BCReceiverA";

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver();
    }

    private void registerReceiver()
    {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "register receiver.");
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
                android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Receive broadcast. " + msg);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("msg", msg + "pass through ReceverA");
                setResultExtras(bundle);
                abortBroadcast();
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.czou_broadcast");
        intentFilter.setPriority(1000);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);


    }

    private void unregisterReceiver()
    {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "unregister receiver.");
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);     
    }    
}
```

You can find, in BCSender, I use `sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, BC_PERMISSION)`, the result is that BCReceiverA can not receive the broadcast, neither `sendBroadcast(intent, BC_PERMISSION)`. But if I use `sendBroadcast(intent)`, receiver can get it.

So what's wrong with `sendBroadcast()/sendOrderedBroadcast()` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `<user-permission>`. The element name is supposed to be `<uses-permission>`.

Also, you may wish to declare the `<permission>` element in both apps, so the order of their installation does not matter. Otherwise, the `<permission>` app *has* to be installed *before* the `<uses-permission>` app.

Comment: @posaidong can you please post your manifest file of both the application. It will be a help.

Comment: @posaidong can you please explain me that How you are calling another application ? and please explain me the sendBroadcast() method.

Comment: @SanghatiMukherjee I don't calling another application from a application, I just want to send broadcast to notify another application.
As you can see, i have posted part of the manifest:
sender define the permission: "com.czou.permission.BC";
and receiver declare the permission: "com.czou.permission.BC".
That's it.